# Updating values to a table based on another table slow

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I wanted to know why my select statement is orders of magnitude faster than my update statement when updating values from one table to another as opposed to selecting values from one table to another. The example below illustrates my problem, I can run my select statement very quickly

```
select customers.name, countries.country
from customers
inner join countries on customers.countrycode = countries.countrycode
```

However the update statement that I've written (which I'm fairly sure is the same thing) takes orders of magnitude longer to complete.

```
update customers
set customers.country = countries.country
from customers
inner join countries on customers.countrycode = countries.countrycode
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Below is the plan for the SELECT statement

```
  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([countries].[countrycode])=([Testing].[dbo].[customers].[countrycode]), RESIDUAL:(@countries.[countrycode] as [countries].[countrycode]=[Testing].[dbo].[customers].[countrycode]))
       |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@countries AS [countries]))
       |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([Testing].[dbo].[customers]))
```

Below is the plan for the UPDATE statement

```
  |--Table Update(OBJECT:([Testing].[dbo].[Customers]), SET:([Testing].[dbo].[Customers].[Country] = @countries.[country] as [countries].[country]))
       |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
            |--Stream Aggregate(GROUP BY:([Bmk1000]) DEFINE:([countries].[country]=ANY(@countries.[country] as [countries].[country])))
                 |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:(@countries.[countrycode] as [countries].[countrycode]=[Testing].[dbo].[Customers].[countrycode]))
                      |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([Testing].[dbo].[Customers]))
                      |--Table Scan(OBJECT:(@countries AS [countries]))
```

Comment: Could you please post the plan for both queries? Run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON GO` and then run the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `UPDATE` alters the table. This means heavy `I/O` on transaction log and on the datafiles themselves if a checkpoint occurs during the update.

A `DML` operation is no way faster than a query.

Second, how do you measure the speed? `SQL Server` can return first records much sooner (and even unproportionally sooner) than all records, depending on the query plan used and how is the cache populated.

**Update:**

From your plan I can see that no `UNIQUE` key is defined for `countries.countrycode`.

`SQL Server` has to find a single value for each `countrycode` to assign to `customers` (even there is a single value in fact) and does a `Stream Aggregate` for this.

Create a `PRIMARY KEY` on `countries.countrycode`.

Comment: The select operation outlined above takes approximately 3 seconds, the update statement takes well in excess of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**Indexes**

If you have multiple indexes on `customers`, every updated row updates every index.  This is a resource-intensive process.  Indexes speed up selects but slow down updates/inserts (as a rule).

Comment: Would this be the case if there was a foreign key constraint on my customers table (say customer_id)? I've not got any indexes on my customers table, but the table that the foreign key comes from has lots.

Comment: @Anish Patel - If  you are not changing the columns in that table with the indexes then no, it shouldn't affect it as far as I know.  Do you have a clustered index on `customers`?  If not, add one and see how that affects it.

Answer (score 0):

Select has (if data is not already on memory) I/O out of Disk.

Update has Read I/O, Write to Log I/O and Write to memory I/O. So I guess it should take longer anyway.

But you should try to create a clustered index if you can choose a slim clustered index key, that would probably speed things up.